# How to read first 1000 entries in a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file containing 60,000 entries. I read them and store in a nested list like this:

```
entries = []
with open('mnist_train.csv', 'r') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in mycsv:
        entries.append(row)
```

Instead of reading all 60,000 how would I read only the first thousand entries?

I tried this without success:

```
entries = []
with open('mnist_train.csv', 'r') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in mycsv[:1000]:
        entries.append(row)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've discovered a `csv.reader` does not support slicing. You can use [itertools.islice()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to accomplish this with objects that are iterable. E.g.,

```
import itertools

entries = []
with open('mnist_train.csv', 'r') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    for row in itertools.islice(mycsv, 1000):
        entries.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas library-

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/file.csv',nrows=1000)
data_list = data.values.tolist() #creates a list of the first 1000 rows (excludes header)
```